# missing files in git repository

Tags: git, github

I created a repository in github, and in my computer I created a folder cloned the repository and in that folder I added another folder with some files and after adding and commiting I pushed them to repository. but in the repository in my folder there is nothing. It should have a html-css folder and inside asset folder and index.html file.

[this is my repository](https://github.com/mssoheil/howto_examples)

Comment: Will you share the command you used to add/stage, commit and push to github? Looking from your repository, html-css was added as a submodule.

Comment: I used git add --all and commited then when I used git status there was untracked changes I used all of git add command but it didn't change so i navigated inside iconBar and inside html-css and added by using *.extension and came back to the outer folder and used git commit and git push

Comment: `git add .` will add everything. It's possible your push didn't went through check first in your commit logs in git

Comment: I used git add . too. the git log shows my commit

Comment: Can you check whether you have a `.git` folder in your html-css folder? That may be the reason it was added as a submodule.

Comment: yes I have a .git. so how should I have done commiting without creating that submodule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your github repository, I find that html-css folder was created as a submodule. The reason is because html-css has a .git folder and that causes github to add html-css as a submodule instead.

What you should have done was to clean up the folder by removing remnant .git folder within subfolders before pushing.

Comment: so you mean that when I couldn't add the changes I should go inside the folder and add and commit then com out and add commit and then remove the inner .git file and push?

Comment: You should remove any .git folder before git init.

Comment: Not sure why you couldn't add it in the first place. Was it originally an empty folder? I suggest you start from fresh and try it all over again, but this time remember to clean up .git folder before git init.